# How to creat a time vector excluding the system date when using R?

Tags: r, time, ggplot2

I want to creat a time vector which starts at 0:05:00 A.M and ends at 0:00:00 A.M the next day.The interval between each time spot is 5 minutes;
Then I want a y-t line plot with qplot().

Here is my R code:

`t<-strptime('0:05:00','%H:%M:%S')+(0:287)*300
y<-rnorm(288,5,1)
qplot(t,y,geom = 'line')`

the outcome is like this:
[image: outcom]

As you can see, the 't' is added with system date 'Aug 05'.What I want is 'hour : minute' only.

What should I do with my code?

Comment: See `chron` package. This question has been asked before.

Comment: Could you give me some more details about this solution or the link to that asked question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `ggplot2` and `POSIX` formatting for dates which is easy to manipulate with ggplot:

```
df = data.frame(
t = seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 05:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-01-02 00:00:00"), by = '5 min', tz = "Europe"), 
y = rnorm(229,5,1))

ggplot(df, aes(t, y)) + geom_line() + 
scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format('%H:%M', tz = "GMT"), breaks =  date_breaks('2 hours'))
```

[image]

Comment: Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : 
  could not find function "date_format"

Comment: I use `df = data.frame(
t = seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:05:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-01-02 00:00:00"), by = '5 min', tz = "Europe"), 
y = rnorm(288,5,1))

ggplot(df, aes(t, y)) + geom_line() + 
scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format('%H:%M', tz = "GMT"), breaks =  date_breaks('2 hours'))` and the t in xlab starts from 16:00:00 to the 16:00:00 in the next day.Why this happened?

Comment: I used `tz = "Europe"`, modify this to your timezone, or delete it.

Comment: That does help.Really appreciate your patient answer!

Comment: You can now modify x ticks easily in `date_breaks` and the x labels in `date_format`.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to manually set the tick labels.  Note that in the snippet below, I amended slightly your code for `t` and `y`, so that they start and end at `0:00:00` (instead of starting at `0:05:00`).

```
t <- strptime('0:00:00','%H:%M:%S')+(0:288)*300
y <- c(NA, rnorm(288,5,1))
tlabs <- format(t, "%H:%M")
breaks <- seq(1, 289, 72)
qplot(as.numeric(t),y,geom = 'line') + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels=tlabs[breaks], breaks=as.numeric(t)[breaks]) +
  xlab("t")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: There is 288 observations in y. If I use '' breaks <- seq(1,288,72) '', the time in xlab is weired...

Comment: Weird in what sense?  That's why I set `t` as a vector of length 289, not 288. You can append an `NA` to the start of `y` (corresponding to time 00:00) if your first observation is at 00:05.